# Empty field check

Tags: javascript

I have the flowing code working fine however I need to check for empty field, and if the field is empty show message and **NOT** go to the new page. I keep trying to add the code to it but it crashes HELP

Find

```
<script>
    function gotoURL(){
        var newURL = document.GotoForm.theURL.value
        document.location.href="http://www.bluediamond.tv/jobs/" + newURL
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <form action="JavaScript:gotoURL()" method="GET" name="GotoForm">
        <p align="center"><input maxlength="100" name="theURL" size="20" type=“find” value="" align="middle" /></p>
        <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="View Photographs" /></p>
    </form> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so first add this inside your input's tag

```
class="myInput"
```

Then update your function

```
function gotoURL(){
        if($('.myInput').val() == ""){
                alert('please fill this field');
        }else{
                var newURL = $('.myInput').val();
                document.location.href="http://www.bluediamond.tv/jobs/" + newURL;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below...

```
function gotoURL(){
  var newURL = document.GotoForm.theURL.value;
  if(newURL && newURL.trim()) {
    document.location.href="http://www.bluediamond.tv/jobs/" + newURL.trim();
  } else {
    alert("Please fill the URL");
  }
}
```